Use a custom logger, with go echo framework
i am trying to apply a format to my loggin, with request specific details in the format. EX: when i log "Test log" I should expected to be logged like:
2024-06-22T19:36:48+01:00 INFO [request_id=14fbf2eb-0793-4efb-ab05-7cd1ebd203ef][appName=test][method=GET][path=/test]  Test log

I came up with a solution that is to create a new logger and bind it to the context.
using "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware", "github.com/labstack/gommon/log" we have:
func BindLoggerToCtx(c echo.Context) {
    id, err := uuid.NewRandom()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    format := fmt.Sprintf("[request_id=%s][appName=%s][method=%s][path=%s] ",
        id.String(),
        msConfig.GetConfig().Info.App.Name,
        c.Request().Method,
        c.Request().RequestURI)

    logger := log.New(format)
    logger.SetHeader("${time_rfc3339} ${level} ${prefix}")
    c.SetLogger(logger)
}

And in the echo Handler FUNC:
e.GET("/test", func(c echo.Context) error {
        middleware.BindLoggerToCtx(c)
        c.Logger().Info("Test log")
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
    })

The goal is that every log i make with
c.Logger().Info("some log"), logs the request specific data.
I wonder if this is efficient or not, applying the logger directly into Echo.context, because we have to create a logger for each incoming request. But I found no other way to do this. Well I though of dependency injection and passing a logger object from TOP DOWN, but i would also like to avoid that. Is there any better efficient way to achieve this?

You can checkout the new RequestLogger for an example for your use case.

The thing is echo only logs the requests and responses that are done to the application, when trying to log a custom message it dosent even log anything :/
